# No more allure-results for cucumber after adding spring-boot framework

Tags: cucumber, allure, cucumber-spring

No more allure-results for cucumber after adding spring-boot framework

Our test-framework version-1 (TF.v1) uses cucumber 7.11.2.
Launching tests with maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M7. Among other things, surefire creates target/allure-results. After that we can generate allure-report, all good.

Our TF.v2 needs to use spring-boot, after we've added it, surefire doesn't produce the target/allure-results anymore.

When debugging and having breakpoint in the class io.qameta.allure.cucumber7jvm.AllureCucumber7Jvm - debugger stops with TF.v1, but not with TF.v2.

Here is a snippet with the maven plugins configuration - we use the same in both TF.v1 and TF.v2
-> https://codefile.io/f/0V8tJqGJ08

Is it a known issue that spring-boot interferes with allure.cucumber7jvm?